# Bootstrap's affix plugin not responsive for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do you make Bootstrap's `affix` plugin responsive? I have my menu placed underneath the Jumbotron and the affix works well. However, when resizing the screen the `data-offset-top` attribute is set to the screen size I was working with at the time. As soon as the height changes, the menu bar is at the wrong height.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="397" role="navigation">
```

Comment: depends on the height, data-offset-top doesn't work responsively.

Comment: Yeah i know it doesn't work responsively, i thought everything in Bootstrap was for responsive design though.

Comment: Not everything, it just serves like a base to help you start, you still have to do the furnishing though

Comment: Thanks...i might just put the navbar on the top of the page then...its probably not possible to have it under the jumbotron header.